# Don't understand why my "if" statement isn't working

Tags: python

I am making a pretty advanced Python program, but no matter how I do it, I cannot get the IF statements to work.

I ran the script all by itself and it still doesn't work.

```
TESTLETTER = input ("Input text here")

if TESTLETTER == 1:

    print ("Logging in...")
```

What is supposed to happen is (in the full program) when you press 1 it will go through a huge process, but here I can't even get it to print text.

Comment: Input is always read as a string. You need to check if `TESTLETTER == ‘1’`

Comment: Do you know about types? `input` returns a string (in python3), whereas `1` is an integer.

Comment: This is Python 3, I take it?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` function returns a string, so it will never be equal to integer 1. Try

```
TESTLETTER = input("Input text here")
if TESTLETTER == "1":
    print ("Logging in...")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you want check if the user has given any input or not.

The correct way to do this on Python would be just to evaluate the string itself. If it's empty or `None`, it'll evaluate to `False`; otherwise, to `True`:

```py
TESTLETTER = input("Input text here")
if TESTLETTER:
    print("Logging in...")
```

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you want just to type `1`, without needing to press `Enter`.

To do that, use the following code if you are on Linux :

```py
import getch

TESTLETTER = getch.getch()
if TESTLETTER == "1":
    print ("Logging in...")
```

If you are on windows, use the following code instead :

```py
import msvcrt 

TESTLETTER = msvcrt.getch()
if TESTLETTER == "1":
    print ("Logging in...")
```